# Multiple validation pipes

Tags: nestjs

In main.ts I have set a Global Pipe looking like this:

```
app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
      whitelist: true,
      transform: true,
      transformOptions: { enableImplicitConversion: true },
    })
  );
```

At the controller level I have a pipe set up this way:

`@UsePipes(new ValidationPipe({ transform: true }))`

My question is: which Pipe is used at the controller level? Will the whitelist property from global Pipe stack up and apply also on the controller ( making the controller level pipe to be useless ), or the controller pipe is the one overriding the global settings, thus the only ValidationPipe operation will be `transform:true`?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **both** pipes will be used. [According to the docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/request-lifecycle#pipes) the global pipe will be applied first, then the controller level pipe will be applied. This will probably result in an error due to trying to re-call `plainToClass`, but if not then it will just end up in taking extra time for the request

Comment: Is there a way to disable global one when local one is used?

Comment: Nope. If it's turned on globally, it;s gonna be used. If it's Nest's `ValidationPipe`, you can _technically_ get around it by now providing a concrete type (an interface, a union, a generic, etc), but that could mess up your other pipes depending on how it works